# About official robotics system toolbox Matlab and Peter Corke Robotics toolbox matlab

Tags: robotic-arm, matlab, robotics-toolbox, robotics-system-toolbox

I came to know that matlab released robotics system toolbox in 2016 version but I'm using Matlab 2014b. At that time I installed Peter Corke Robotics toolbox matlab and start working on it. I develop few GUI and wrote others code too using the same Peter Corke Robotics toolbox. But now I want to install new official version of robotics toolbox. But my doubt is if I install new version then what happen to older one. Will I  able to run my old codes (which used old toolbox) on matlab after installing new official version or it may vanish older one. Will matlab shows error in my codes or GUI after installing new version. I want to work with both toolbox.

Thanks.

Comment: Peter Corke's Robotics toolbox and MATLAB's official Robotics System Toolbox are geared towards somewhat different things. Some functions like RPY to rotation matrix etc. might be present in both toolboxes but it's unlikely they would have the exact same names (for example, Euler to rotation matrix in MATLAB's toolbox is eul2rotm, in Dr Corke's toolbox is eul2tr.. etc.).

Answer (score 6):

There are very few problems having both toolboxes installed.  The biggest gotcha is the function angdiff() which is provided by both toolboxes but defined differently.

If you want to stick with MATLAB 2014b you should use RTB9.10.

Comment: That was indeed the biggest gotcha for me so far! I wish this were more highlighted somewhat, although it didn't take me too much time to find out.

Comment: My Toolbox now ships with a script called rvccheck that checks for these kind of clashes.